# percona tool pt-trend output meaning?

Tags: mysql, percona

Recently, I am using [percona-toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit). One of tools is pt-trend. It is used like`pt-trend mysql-slow`, and it's output as followings:

- 1344442759   1.000000   0.004988   0.004988   0.004988   0.004988
- 1344442763   2.000000   1.124892   0.000889   1.124003   0.562446
- 1344442764 133.000000   1.609606   0.000284   1.483041   0.012102

What does each column mean? I can't find information on the percona official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pt-trend source:

```
ts, cnt, sum, min, max, avg, stdev
```